# Analysis services cube in Tableau

Tags: ssas, tableau-api

I'm trying to analyse data from my cube from Analysis Services in Tableau. My cube is:

[image: Cube]

And now I'd like to count number of facts that happened in each state (state is connected through city).But when I'm choosing StateID from DimStates Tableau shows, that data are incompatible. Is there any way to join them? Counting number of facts in each city work well.

[image: Error]

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Tableau's functionality is severely limited when working with cube data sources. I can't see exactly what you're trying to do, but it looks like you're trying to add a table calculation to the measure in your view which (depending on the aggregation) isn't supported:

> Cube data sources are pre-aggregated and thus do not support aggregation functions, such as SUM(), AVG(), and CNT().
>   It may be possible to use Table Calculations to perform aggregation operations on the cell-level results from the cube in Tableau.

https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/cubes.htm